# Total points from achievements

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

What is the maximum possible achievement point/score total in *StarCraft II*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the total is 4960.

[This player](http://kr.battle.net/sc2/ko/profile/305393/1/%EC%9E%89%EC%97%AC/) seems to have gotten them all. (Link is from the Korean Battle.net)

Comment: Here is a thread discussing the same player: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=159847

Comment: Ditto. Although I can recall there being some discussion about the campaign listing 1590 out of 1600 possible points. Never followed that through though, so I wouldn't know what it is at.

Comment: @wormintrude: I think I heard somewhere that the actual total for the Liberty campaign is in fact 1590, but there's a bug where it displays your percent completed as 99% instead of 100%.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: The Liberty campagn has 1590 and it displays correctly 100% at least for me.